# How can i access content type properties of an excel workbook in ExcelScript?

Tags: excel, vba, office-scripts, excel-online

I have this little script in VBA to fill fields with content type properties assigend on SharePoint.

```vb
Function SHAREPOINTPROPERTY(sPropertyName As String) As String
SHAREPOINTPROPERTY = Application.ThisWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties(sPropertyName)
End Function
```

This does not work, when i open files with Excel Online. For that reason I would like to convert this to a ExcelScript function which runs on open. Is this even possible and how would i approach this?

I've been looking at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.documentproperties?view=office-scripts) but have not found much regarding my usecase.

Comment: Could you share a bit more about what you're trying to achieve? Currently, Excel doesn't support automatically running an Office Script on workbook open, but Power Automate might be able to help you.

Comment: I set document properties of the file in Sharepoint (columns) and i want the values to be displayed in a cell of the workbook. Currently the only way i see to do this is with the VBA script but like that values are not displayed until someone opened it at least once in the desktop app.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a Power Automate flow that triggers when a file is modified in SharePoint, then pass the file properties into an Office Script that writes the values into a workbook? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#when-a-file-is-created-or-modified-(properties-only) Happy to help with a more detailed solution if this seems to be the right direction for you.